# How MongoDB replicates data in sharded cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

At what level does MongoDB replicates data in sharded cluster?

1. At chunk level. Mongodb creates/syncs replicas for each chunk.
2. At the whole server level. Mongodb just syncs the state of the shard server to other shard servers.

Comment: Replication and sharding are two _different_ concepts. Replication is about keeping multiple mongodb server data in sync - within a replica-set. Each write operation on a primary is replicated on other members of the replica-set. Sharding is about distributing data among different shards in a sharded cluster. That said, each shard in a sharded cluster is a replica-set.

Comment: Can a secondary replica for a shard be on another shard server? 
For example, how many separate nodes are required for 3 shards with replication factor=3? 9 nodes? 3 for shards and 6 for secondary replicas?

Comment: You can refer this further: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/